# How to count occurrences across rows within the same column by multiple conditions

Tags: r, multiple-conditions, multiple-occurrence

I have the following dataset on R:

| patent_id | CPC |
| --- | --- |
| xxxxxx | Y02P |
| xxxxxx | H01M |
| xxxxxx | GO1H |
| xxxxxx | AO2A |
| yyyyyy | A01B |
| yyyyyy | Y02E |
| yyyyyy | Y02T |
| yyyyyy | Y04S |

For each CPC equal to CPC-Y02 (Y02A, Y02B, Y02C, Y02D, Y02E, Y02P, Y02T, Y02W, Y04S) for each patent_id, I need to count how many times the other CPC occurs, to find to which CPC different from the list, each Y02 are associated the most.

I have tried with duplicating the column of CPC to count across the two columns but I get the number of occurrences fro each CPC with itself:

`x <- y %>% group_by(CPC_4digit, CPC_dup) %>%  summarise(n=n()) %>%  spread(CPC_dup, n, fill = 0L)`

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: include the result you expect from the table above

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(patent_id = c("xxxxxx",
                     "xxxxxx",
                     "xxxxxx",
                     "xxxxxx",
                     "yyyyyy",
                     "yyyyyy",
                     "yyyyyy",
                     "yyyyyy"),
       CPC = c("Y02P",
               "H01M",
               "GO1H",
               "AO2A",
               "A01B",
               "Y02E",
               "Y02T",
               "Y04S") ) %>% 
  group_by(patent_id, CPC) %>% 
  mutate(times = n()) %>% 
  group_by(patent_id) %>% 
  mutate(totaltimes = n()) %>% 
  transmute(patent_id, CPC, other_times = totaltimes - times)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   patent_id [2]
  patent_id CPC   other_times
  <chr>     <chr>       <int>
1 xxxxxx    Y02P            3
2 xxxxxx    H01M            3
3 xxxxxx    GO1H            3
4 xxxxxx    AO2A            3
5 yyyyyy    A01B            3
6 yyyyyy    Y02E            3
7 yyyyyy    Y02T            3
8 yyyyyy    Y04S            3
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Not really, maybe I was not clear enough in asking the question. Maybe I would expect a matrix with rows and columns for each CPC, where the entries the number of times the CPC on the column is associated to the CPC in the row (example: G01H is associated 500 times with Y02D, A02A 3000 and so on). By what I have tried I get such a matrix but it counts only the occurrences with itself, so I have a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @user17563853 you should include the matrix that you expect in your question. Note how that was requested an hour ago and yet you havent updated the question with what you expect. Also only include the number of times that appear in the example above and not in the whole dataset